# `TypeError:'module' object is not callable` occurs when I use the line profiler to perform performance statistics

Tags: python

I follow the [line profiler doc]https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler to use line profiler, but `TypeError` will occur during runtime. Below is my program(file name is `fib.py`):

```
import profile


@profile
def primes(n):
    if n == 2:
        return [2]
    elif n < 2:
        return []
    s = range(3, n + 1, 2)
    mroot = n ** 0.5
    half = (n + 1) / 2 - 1
    i = 0
    m = 3
    while m <= mroot:
        if s[i]:
            j = (m * m - 3) / 2
            s[j] = 0
            while j < half:
                s[j] = 0
                j += m
        i = i + 1
        m = 2 * i + 3
    return [2] + [x for x in s if x]


primes(100)
```

The version of line profiler is `3.1.0`, and the run command is `kernprof -l -v fib.py`.

The error detail is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/kernprof", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kernprof.py", line 226, in main
    execfile(script_file, ns, ns)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kernprof.py", line 35, in execfile
    exec_(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), globals, locals)
  File "fib.py", line 4, in <module>
    @profile.Profile(timer=None,bias=None)
TypeError: 'Profile' object is not callable
```

Is my usage incorrect or the profile decorator is not implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import line_profiler
profile = line_profiler.LineProfiler()
```

You Should import the profiler like this and it should work.

After that use the profile to decorate your function

Or Use If you prefer to only import Profiler

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
profile = LineProfiler()
```

Comment: thanks. It works. What I am more confused about is why the documentation does not describe this initialization...

Comment: Welcome i am glad that i could help

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer is to remove `import profile` without replacement. If you run the script via the `kernprof` command, you don't need to import anything in your code, but VS Code's autoimport feature loves to add `import profile`, which will cause problems.

Note that without imports, you have to remove or comment out the `@profile` decorators afterwards because otherwise you can only run your code via `kernprof` but not via a normal `python` call.